# Can't get Server Side Includes (one HTML file into another) to work

Tags: html, server-side-includes

I can't get server side includes to work. I simply want to include one html file into another and I just can't seem to get it working

### **Setup**

The server is a another machine (not localhost) running Windows XP. I've got a slighly older version of the xampp stack which is running only Apache/2.2.11

**Virtual directory (in httpd-vhosts.conf) is configured as**

> ```
> <Directory "c:\www\dev1">
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
>     AllowOverride All
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

**index.html contains**

```
A Big Block of Text<br />
A Big Block of Text<br />

<!-- #include file="test.shtml" -->

A Big Block of Text<br />
A Big Block of Text<br />
```

**test.shtml contains**

```
This is another line
```

### What I am getting

**From the browser on my dev machine, www.dev.com/index.html shows**

```
A Big Block of Text<br />
A Big Block of Text<br />
A Big Block of Text<br />
A Big Block of Text<br />
```

- Page Source shows the !--- include
  which means the include file hasn't
  been processed
- www.dev.com/test.shtml
  shows the file as indicated above so
  it is accessible.

### Things I've tried

Read through a bunch of posts both here on stackoverflow and the internet and its helped "build" the basics for getting this to work (ie make sure Options has Includes enabled) but it still isn't working.

Changed

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI to
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes +Include ExecCGI to
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +Includes ExecCGI
```

with an apache restart and it still doesn't work

Added .htaccess to the same directory as index.html and test.shtml

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI 
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
```

and it still doesn't work.

Note. http.conf already has

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
```

enabled.

Yes, it is probably something real obvious but I've got a cold so if somebody could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

### More Things I've Tried

Change include file to include virtual

I tried the suggestion by RichieHindle and it didn't seem to work and I've modified both my .htaccess and virtual directory configuration to include required combinations of AddType, AddHandler for both .html and .shtml ... still nothing

BIG NOTE: On the webserver, one can load a SSI checking webpage (via localhost in one of the xampp install directories) and it tells me that SSI includes are enabled and working, however, please note that my virtual directories are NOT in the xampp install directories; they are standalone under c:/www ... but I can't figure out how/why this makes a difference if I've configured the options outlined above in my virtual directory settings and/or .htaccess settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try removing the space? From:

```
<!-- #include file="test.shtml" -->
```

to this:

```
<!--#include file="test.shtml" -->
```

Comment: Okay, I knew I was going to do at least one facepalm here. This (along with RichieHadle's pointer that I need to parse HTML files for includes) got it working. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6):

Do you need:

```
AddHandler server-parsed .html
```

?

Your HTML file is named index.html but you're only applying `server-parsed` to .**s**html files.

Comment: Okay if it is only parsing .Shtml files ... Copied index.html to index.shtml and loaded index.shtml in the browser ... nope, it didn't include the requested file.

Comment: and I tried adding    AddType text/html .shtml
   AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
   AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html

   AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
   AddHandler server-parsed .html
to my virtual directory configuration and still not including (loading either the .html file or .shtml file)

Comment: yeah, the problem was "server-parsed .shtml", it must be server-parsed .html

Answer (score 0):

I have searched and tried ALOT when it comes to including html in another html file. I did NOT want to use .asp or .php or .xhtml.

this worked for me: [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)